# Recovering 18fps super-8 from NTSC 59.94i: Duplicate frame removal?

Tags: framerate, post-production

I have a VHS tape made from 1970s-era super-8 home video footage (the originals for which are lost), and am trying to make what improvements I can.

I used a Blackmagic UltraStudio to perform raw frame captures of the component output from a Panasonic DMR-ES46V (avoiding encoding artifacts from using that hardware's on-board MPEG encoder to write to DVD). The result is not great -- the footage was underlit, and a lot of shadow detail, as far as I can tell, is simply unrecoverable -- but the thing I *would* hope to fix is the duplicated frames.

The conversion from 18p to 59.94i was not pretty: there are repeated frames, frames with interlace artifacts (which I *can* correct with existing tools), and frames that mix two original frames. It's those last ones I have no idea how to deal with; if both those and the duplicated frames are gone, I presume I'll be able to use something like Topaz Video's retiming capabilities to get a reasonable result (whether at 18fps or otherwise)

Are tools available to identify and remove frames? I mostly use Davinci Resolve on MacOS (and also have Linux hosts at hand); the only tool I've seen so far that looks plausible for the purpose is [the Srestore script for avisynth](http://avisynth.nl/index.php/Srestore); but this appearing to be an unmaintained Windows-only tool, I'm hoping that plausible alternatives exist.

Comment: In hindsight, I think these mixed frames are artifacts from deinterlacing. BTW, the shadow detail I _thought_ was unrecoverable turned out to still be there by turning the gain up on the UltraStudio's composite interfaces, and mixing the shadows from the high-gain recording with the midtones and highlights of the low-gain recording in the style of HDR processing.